# Multiple build commands for output file in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

My xCode project for an OSX app gives me the following error.

> Warning: Multiple build commands for output file
>
> /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Flui-dpvozbfxcmsipwfrrannskcofgit/Build/Products/Debug/appname.app/Contents/Resources/Icons

Is this something I should be worried about or fix immediately?
Also is there a way to make this go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the **Copy Bundle Resources** from the **Build Phase** in your project. Find the duplicate files in that list and delete their references.